# Full-height sidebar with 2 stacked divs - one needs to have dynamic height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a layout that's fixed width sidebar and fluid content. There are two divs inside my sidebar, and the sidebar has enough content to reach the end of the page. However, there are cases that it may extend beyond that. The first div (the one on top) has static content; the second one is a dynamic menu.

What I want to achieve is to have the height of the 2nd div become something like:

"window height - height of first div"

In smaller browsers, the 2nd div may extend beyond the bottom of the page so it also needs to scroll.

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar-container">
    <div id="sidebar-content">
        <div id="sidebar-main">
            STATIC WORDPRESS MENU
        </div>

        <div id="sidebar-menu">
            DYNAMIC MENU. I need this div to change in height 
            according to the browser's height.
        </div><!--sidebar-menu-->       
    </div><!--sidebar-content-->
</div><!--sidebar-container-->
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar-container {
background-color: #000;
width: 300px;
float: left;
left: 300px;
margin-left: -300px;
position: relative;
overflow-y: auto;
height: auto
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery solution. It does exactly what you asked for i.e. window height - height of first div.

```
var maxHeight = 0;
$(window).load(function() {
    maxHeight = $(window).height() - $('#sidebar-main').height();
    $('#sidebar-menu').height(maxHeight);
});
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAC84/QxN8T/1/) of it working. Bear in mind that jsFiddle automatically adds the `$(window).load` event but you may still need it in your code.